# change dataLabels on highcharts based on color of bar

Tags: jquery, highcharts

so i create a diagram with highchart and i try custom color on bar, i try to make the data label to have the same color as the bar. At first my data label didnt change color. but when i resize the window, data label's color suddenly changed. how to make change color as soon as the page load? (without trigger with resize).

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter:function() {
            var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
            // return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
            return '<tspan style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%' + '</tspan>';
        }
```

the full code is in [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erzLRR)

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this issue is that data labels are rendered **before** SVG patterns that you defined in options in `colors` array are created. Chart is redrawn when you change the width of the container and proper values are applied.

**Before redraw** (`[object Object]` isn't a correct value of `fill`):

```
<tspan style="fill:[object Object]" x="5" y="16">25.00%</tspan>
```

**After redraw:**

```
<tspan style="fill:url(#highcharts-gbd5ohb-4)" x="5" y="16">25.00%</tspan>
```

I don't think that it can be considered as a bug - the **API** specifies that only hex color values are supported: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors

As a **workaround** you can move the `dataLabels.formatter` definition to `update` function in `chart.events.load`:

```
events: {
   load: function() {         
     this.update({
       plotOptions: {
          series: {
             dataLabels: {
               formatter:function() {
                  var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
                  // return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                   return '<tspan style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%' + '</tspan>';
              }}
          }
       }
     });
   }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeGWrx